# How to find the odds of a horse wining a race?

Tags: probability-theory

The odds against a horse winning are 2 to 1. What is the probability of this horse winning?

Comment: solve for $p$ in $p/(1-p)=2/1$

Comment: Assuming that $p$ are the odds of winning, you need to solve $\frac{1-p}{p} = \frac{2}{1}$. This gives $p=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Are these the odds quoted by a bookmaker, or is it a mathematical expression of a known probability? [Bookmakers tend to want to make profits]

Comment: @copper.hat Care to promote that to an answer? This question shouldn't clutter the unanswered queue any longer.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Good suggestion! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $p$ are the odds of winning, you need to solve $\frac{1-p}{p} = \frac{2}{1}$. This gives $p=\frac{1}{3}$.