# Probability on a horse race by randomly selecting a horse

Tags: probability

If I bet $1 on a randomly selected horse in a race with the following odds against (or payout for each 1 dollar bet), how much would I expect to win / lose assuming the horses are priced fairly?

```
2.4
8
3.6
13 
13
26
13
15
17
13
13
61
```

-- thanks.

EDITED: odds to payout to make it clear

With my limited understanding of horse racing, (please correct me if I'm wrong) a payout of 2.4 implies the horse has a 1/(2.4 + 1) = 0.294 chance of winning. Source: [How to find the odds of a horse wining a race?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146392/how-to-find-the-odds-of-a-horse-wining-a-race)

Comment: Surely the odds should sum to $\le 1$?

Comment: A payoff of $r$ on a $1$ dollar bet is fair if the probability of winning is $1/r$.  In this case the sum of the reciprocals of your numbers is greater than $1$.  Therefore those horses are not priced fairly.

Comment: @copper.hat - I've updated the question, sorry if the odds terminology wasn't clear. I meant the payout.

Comment: @richarddruce: You are right, I didn't read carefully enough!

Comment: The $1/(2.4 + 1)$ would be correct if in addition to the payout of $2.4$ you got your original dollar back.  I was assuming that's not the case in horse racing.

Answer (score 2):

If the horses were priced fairly, no matter what bet you make you would expect to break even.  But that's certainly not the case here.  If you get your dollar back in addition to the listed payoffs, the probability of an outcome with payoff $r$ should be $1/(r+1)$.  If you don't, it should be $1/r$.  But neither the 
$1/r$'s nor the $1/(r+1)$'s add up to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

E[X] = sum of $xp(x)$...Do you know how to find $p(x)$ here? HINT: The odds are a ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this race, but here's something to consider (assuming this question to be of a practical nature, and not pure mathematics.)  Having kept my own records for some time, I've found that eliminating the top and bottom 1/4 to 1/3, (i.e. favorites and long shots) and playing the "middle" with either random selections or full coverage (all of the middle) pays a profit consistently over time; not a big one, but a consistent one.  Why?  Don't know.  Perhaps this is a question more for psychologists than mathematicians, given that all wagering these days is (in theory) pari-mutual.  I'd love to see this explained mathematically...